# File re-direction operator ">" doesn't work with CreateProcess() API

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, file-io, createprocess

I've a SupportApp.EXE which if I launch manually from windows CMD prommpt like this ::

```
SupportApp.EXE -t 100 > AFile.csv
```

works perfcetly fine & it generates a CSV file for me.

Now I want to automate same thing inside a VC++ code.
So, I use CreateProcess() API for this.
 Code snippet below ::

```
TCHAR launcher[512];
    _tgetcwd(launcher, _MAX_PATH);
    TCHAR workDir[512];
    _tgetcwd(workDir, _MAX_PATH);
    _tcscat(launcher, "\\App\\SupportApp.exe");
    TCHAR cmdlineoption[512];
    _tcscpy(cmdlineoption, " -t 120 > AFile.csv");
LPTSTR appPath = (LPTSTR)cmdlineoption;


    STARTUPINFO sInfo;
    memset(&sInfo, 0, sizeof(sInfo));
    sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
    sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    sInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    memset(&pInfo, 0, sizeof(pInfo));

    if (!CreateProcess(launcher, appPath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, workDir, &sInfo, &pInfo))
{
... // log error
}
// success
```

I see that CreateProcess() API succeeds and also i see that the -t 120 option I'm giving is also taken by this "SupportApp.exe" 
BUT the file redirection operator ">" is not working with CreateProcess() API.

Instead the output is directed to CMD itself. But I want output to be sent to a CSV file.

> Can anyone please help me in how do I redirect the output of my
>   "SupportApp.exe" to a file using CreateProcess() API from within my
>   VC++ code ?

***UPDATE 2:***

The inputs given by reviewers are incorporated in this & the modified code snippet is below which takes the file hnadle in STARTUPINFO structure as follows::

The file is getting created but the file is empty & it doesn't have any contents from createProcess()?

```
TCHAR launcher[512];
        _tgetcwd(launcher, _MAX_PATH);
        TCHAR workDir[512];
        _tgetcwd(workDir, _MAX_PATH);
        _tcscat(launcher, "\\App\\SupportApp.exe");
        TCHAR cmdlineoption[512];
        _tcscpy(cmdlineoption, " -t 120 > AFile.csv");
    LPTSTR appPath = (LPTSTR)cmdlineoption;


        STARTUPINFO sInfo;
        memset(&sInfo, 0, sizeof(sInfo));
        sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
        sInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES; //newly added
        sInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
        memset(&pInfo, 0, sizeof(pInfo));

        sInfo.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        sInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);        

       SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
     ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
      sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
```

HANDLE hn;

if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != (hn = CreateFile(L"DoneDone.csv", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, &sa, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)))
{
  sInfo.hStdOutput =  =hn;
}
            if (!CreateProcess(launcher, appPath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, workDir, &sInfo, &pInfo))
        {
        ... // log error
        }
        // success

Answer (score 3):

Output redirection is a shell feature, i.e. the shell sets that up before starting the child.

You're not using a shell, instead going directly to the kernel asking it to start a process, so you don't get that service.

You need to set up the required redirection yourself. This is done in the `STARTUPINFO`'s `hStdOutput` member. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), of course.

Comment: Can I please request you for providing a code sample on how to achieve this redirection using  STARTUPINFO's hStdOutput field ?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the redirection operations (as well as the pipe operation) is part of the command prompt program, not part of the `CreateProcess` call.

However, you can do exactly what the command prompt program does when it does redirection, and set the file handles in the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Comment: Can I please request you for providing a code sample on how to achieve this redirection using STARTUPINFO's hStdOutput field ?

Comment: @codeLover See [this `CreateFile` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for info about how to open file. Just assign the returned handle to `hStdOutput` of the structure. There are many example of both using `CreateFile` and `CreateProcess` with "redirection" on the Internet if you just search a little.

Comment: I tried using CreateProcess() along with CreateFile() and gave the HANDLE of teh file to the "hStdOutput" filed of teh structure STARTUPINFO. But I'm seeing that the output is not getting redirected to the file I created using CreateFile. Any pointers why is it so ?

Comment: @codeLover You did check that the file was opened correctly, and in the correct mode? Also, update your question to show the new code and your new experiences.

Comment: yes i did check for teh file permissions and I've updated this question with the new code in "Update2 section".